# I paid my CC payment on it's due date and it states posted but no money has yet to come out of my bank account, is my payment still on time?

Tags: credit-card

So I paid my CC payment on the date it was due which was a Saturday. My CC payments state that the transaction is "posted" and no longer processing which is great but, no money has left the checking account I use to pay my credit card. Is my CC payment still on time?

Comment: So long as the system accepts and marks the payment on or before the due date, then as far as they are concerned it is on time, however, it may not leave your account right away as it takes time for it to be processed and outside of business days, it can take slightly longer to show up.

Comment: My experience (US bank) is that it ALWAYS takes 1-3 days for the payment to show up in my bank account.

Answer (score 1):

The "on time" aspect is typically the time you've made the payment to the credit card system, not the time that the money is removed from your account. The payment is "in limbo" in the banking system, but your statements reflect an on-time payment.

As an example, I paid on the due date (sunday) and was charged a late fee, explained later that the processing is suspended on a sunday, but the charge was reversed, as the credit card processing online showed an on-time payment.

Your documentation with respect to the statements is your protection if there is a charge, allowing it to be easily reversed.